# Why does the safe area for iPad apps running on mac OS does not pin to top of the view?

Tags: ios, macos, ipad, autolayout, safearea

I don't understand this empty space left on the top, looks like a space for the status bar but the status bar is not present on Mac os. Am I missing something ?

[image: The purple view is pinned to safe area as you can see in second image]

[image]

Comment: try align Top to: SuperView, constant :0

Comment: Yes that works, but on a real device the view will then be behind the status bar or nav bar and I don't want that.